# Parse names with space as the delimiter?

Tags: python

Assume it is not possible to change the data format. How can I parse names with space as the delimiter when the names themselves contain spaces **and** some names are more than two parts?

**Example**: Iko Uwais Joe Taslim Donny Alamsyah Yayan Ruhian Pierre Gruno Tegar Satrya Ray Sahetapy Gareth Huw Evans Ana De La Reguera Jon Favreau

Comment: This problem is impossible as stated.  To turn this into a possible problem, we would have to have add something.

Comment: The 1st example is impossible.  The 2nd example (with grouping) is trivial.  Can we assume that all input looks like the second example.

Comment: Your constraints are mutually exclusive.  You can't split on spaces and at the same time _not_ split on spaces.

Comment: One possibility would be to assume that all middle names are shorter than 4 characters and all last names have at least 4 characters. In that case `re.findall(r'\w+ (?:\w{,3} )*\w+', text)` would get you all your names nicely separated.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - That breaks for last-names like `Wu`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Like I said - the assumption is that last names have at least 4 characters.

Comment: @emory - The second example is only provided for readability (to easily distinguish where names begin and end).

Comment: You'll have to rely on some sort of heuristic.

Comment: You could find a listing of possible first names and last names, tag each word as a first name or a last name, and then use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: It's impossible. Some names work both as first and last names. Arrange to get your input in a better format.

Comment: You're doomed...